# How could Luke destroy the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars movie, Luke blow up the death star by flying really close to the surface at high speed and shooting a missile straight down.

From what I understand it has to be at 45° before the top of the hole to shoot, like this:

```
 <=L=>mm
         m
           m
            m 
 ----------|m|---------------
           |m|
           |m|
```

Where m is the trajectory used by the missile.

Is there any explanation on how can the missile turn in such a steep way, and why couldn't it be fired from somewhere else, since the missiles seems to have extra high maneuverability ?

Comment: additional discussion at [Why did Luke need a targeting computer in the first place?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8538/5184)

Comment: Explanation is The Force.

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate, I didn't used the right keywords in my search :)

Answer (score 3):

Space magic.... I mean the force.

It was Obi's force ghost telling him to not use instruments and only use the force that allowed the shot to be on target.

Comment: Needs sound https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agcRwGDKulw